# equality between two strings

Tags: java, string

I have a text file with this structure:

```
CRIM:Continuius
ZN:Continuius
INDUS:Continuius
CHAS:Categorical
NOX:Continuius
```

I inserted it into a two dimensional array:

```
BufferedReader description = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fullpath2));
        String[][] desc;
        desc = new String[5][2];

        String[] temp_desc;
        String delims_desc = ":";
        String[] tempString;

        for (int k1 = 0; k1 < 5; k1++) {
            String line1 = description.readLine();
            temp_desc = line1.split(delims_desc);
            desc[k1][0] = temp_desc[0];
            desc[k1][1] = temp_desc[1];
        }
```

and then tried to identify which attribute is Categorical:

```
        String categ = "Categorical";
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
            String temp1 = String.valueOf(desc[i][1]);
            if ("Categorical".equals(desc[i][1])){
                System.out.println("The "+k1+ " th is categorical.");
}
}
```

Why doesn't it return `true`, although one of the attributes is categorical?

Comment: it's either a case problem, in which case use `equalsIgnoreCase` or you don't have the input you think you do

Comment: In any case, run a debugger on that. You'll know soon enough.

Comment: Newline symbol at the end of line1?

Comment: WHy an array, why not a `Map`?

Comment: What happens when you print all the values? Do they match what you expect?

Comment: @thegrinner: Yes. when I print the 2d array, everything is fine, but it cannot recognize CHAS as categorical.

Comment: And if you print the lengths? Is there extra whitespace?

Comment: @thegrinner: Sorry I did not understand your question. You are right. Although I removed extraspaces, but still has problem.

Comment: @VTT: what do you mean with "_still has problem_"?

Comment: It means when I run the code, it cannot recognize CHAS as categorical.

Comment: @VTT: write `System.out.println("\"" + desc[i][1] + "\"");` at the beginning of the `for` loop to check if what is being compared to `"Categorical"`.

Comment: What's the purpose of temp1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the input you posted (in the [edit perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16992670/edit)), I saw there is a lot of trailing whitespace on almost every line of the textfile. Your problem will disappear if you replace

```
desc[k1][1] = temp_desc[1];
```

with

```
desc[k1][1] = temp_desc[1].trim();
```

You could even shorten your code to

```
for (int k1 = 0; k1 < 5; k1++) {
    String line1 = description.readLine().trim();
    desc[k1] = line1.split(delims_desc);
}
```

---

Clarification:

You are trying to compare

```
"Categorical" // 11 characters
```

with

```
"Categorical        " // more than 11 characters
```

and those are not equal strings.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Since there is no space between two words, it is already trimmed.

Comment: @VTT: As said in my answer: the extra whitespace is at the **end** of the line. So you are trying to compare `"Categorical"` with `"Categorical   "` and those are not equal strings.

Comment: Sorry. You are absolutely right. I fixed it, but still has problem.

Comment: @VTT: I posted a solution to the problem you posted. I can not help you further, because "_but still has problem_" isn't specific enough.